# Cronjob does not work

Tags: php, cron

I know that this question was asked many times, but most of the answers are not really useful.

So I edited crontab with `crontab -e`. It was empty and I added just one line

`*/1 * * * * php5 /var/www/cron.php` which I think will be executing cron.php every 1 minute. I saved the file, but it clearly is not executed (inside my php file I have only

```
<?
$file = 'test.txt';
file_put_contents($file, "Work");
```

and it is not created. I looked and modified permissions on cron.php to 777. Php is installed as apache module.

What bothers me is that when I do `php5 /var/www/cron.php` from command line, I just see the content of the file and it not executed.

What am I doing wrong?

I also tried using full path with `*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php5 /var/www/cron.php` but also with no luck.

Comment: Try to provide full-path instead of just the filename.

Comment: To the person who is going to close it. It is not an error. It is the case where a person does not know that configuration files are different for apache running as CLI and as Apache module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first line of the script should be:

```
<?php
```

You may have short tags enabled in the Apache PHP configuration, but not the CLI PHP configuration.

Comment: You're right but I don't think that's the problem cause he can probably run it manually. I believe that the file is being created - only not in the folder he expects...

Comment: He says he can't run it manually. When he tries to run it manually it outputs the script source code, it doesn't run it.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Thank you. I did not know that CLI and Apache have different configurations. Thank you.

Comment: You're probably getting email every minute with the contents of the script.

Comment: @Barmar but I have not provided any email. Where can I check for these emails and how can I disable them?

Comment: cron automatically mails the stdout and stderr of any cron job to the username running the job. To disable them, redirect the output to a file or /dev/null, e.g. `php5 /var/www/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 0):

- Try to use full path of php (e.g. /usr/local/bin/php)
- Try to use `<?php` instead of `<?`